# Spring Boot + Bootstrap + jQuery : Error 404 in $ajax call on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, firefox

I've an application using Spring Boot +  Bootstrap + Thymeleaf. I am trying to make an AJAX call to fill a combox use the jquery. In the Chrome workes well. In the Firefox gives me the 404 message. What could be happend?

The Firefox console.log message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuGri.png)

My AJAX code:

```
    function carregaComboAtivoAjax(url) {
    var Id = document.getElementById('idUo').value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: { Id: Id },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("body").html(data);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    private String carregaComboAtivo(@RequestParam UUID Id,  Model model) {
          ...

    }
```

Best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same problem, that is the solution:

In the spring boot controller method you need write like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/carregaComboAtivoCadastraCampo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE })
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView carregaComboAtivo(@RequestParam UUID uoId,  Model model) {
  ...
}
```

You need to set the media type produces.